# how to get correct position after filtering the Listview in android application

Tags: android, android-listview, textwatcher

In my app, when a user types something in a search box then a list gets filtered but the position of the list items gets changed. And due to this changed position when the user clicks on a list item, it results in unwanted activity. Because I have set events to the list items according to their position. Is there any parameter of the list items/row which remains same even after getting the list filtered?

Comment: Hmmm Deja vu.... Anyway, post your *full* adapter and filtering code. Otherwise we can't say what's wrong. In general, the position you get should be the correct one relative to the filtered adapter data.