# After adding search bar, listview does not launch right html file

Tags: android, listview, webview

I have been working on a project, in which i have a main activity in which i have listview and one search bar(edit text bar) and the onitemclicklistener of my listview passes the row position to a activity having webview and the webview opens html pages to their respective positions. i also have my listview items stored in arrays.xml

my problem starts here- my Listview Works file and opens respective activity on row click (when i dont use search bar and just scroll and click on row.)

but when i use the searchbar to search for an item (html page) for instance let it be "c" and i click on it , the listview DoesNot open the correct html page!. hope this is clear 
 i found one solution here [After filter a listview,how can I obtain the position of the first listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393538/after-filter-a-listview-how-can-i-obtain-the-position-of-the-first-listview)
but i have no idea how do i implement this in my code.

**here is my main activity**

```
 package com.Sample.htmlOpener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView list1;
private String array[] ;
EditText inputSearch; 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); 
    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
    adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
    int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
 });

  list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("key",position);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
  });   
}
}
```

**and here is my webview activity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView web;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
        if(pos==0)
        {
            web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
        }
        else
        {
            web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file" + pos + ".html");
        }
      // similarly for 4 and 5 and so on.
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because if you use searchbar, the positions are changed due to filtering. So if I type 'c' and i get 4 results then the positions would be from 0 to 3. Then since your passing the position of the clicked item it passes the wrong position and not the actual position ! You need to store the positions somehow

Comment: but how do i do that? please help me out

Comment: my problem is i have thousands of html files

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057148/android-listview-search-filter    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605066/how-to-get-correct-position-after-filtering-the-listview-in-android-application               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393538/after-filter-a-listview-how-can-i-obtain-the-position-of-the-first-listview  Hope this helps and solves your problem

Comment: its about getting item position which i already have , but the problem is i cannot store position because i have like thousands of html files which means thousands of else if statements , which i have already tried but i get java heap size error

Comment: Create a HashMap<String,String> and store the position and name. On click get the position by passing in the name. Then pass that position to the next activity. You should be able to do that using for loop.

Comment: i think this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393538/after-filter-a-listview-how-can-i-obtain-the-position-of-the-first-listview

Comment: but i have no idea how to implement this in my code

Comment: in your `onTextChanged` method after `MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);` you should add a code line `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan i tried this, but its still not working, nothing have changed

Comment: @Anonymous you should do your searching using `SQLite database`, insert all your `arrays.xml` data into your database and filter it using `Cursor`, second thing you should make your `ListView` Custom Adapter. Its lengthy but usefull. I did same thing in my app and successfully done.

Comment: can you please tell step by step? that would be helpful and please give it in answer so that i can tick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step by step procedure is provided [here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2013/08/android-listview-with-searchview.html). You can follow this tutorial and easily understand about `custom listview adapter` plus `search functionality using SQLite Database`. 
If you want to understand more about `SQLite` follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

hope you will solve your problem, but learning is must :)

Comment: @Anonymous thats great but its better for you to understand custom adapter for `listview` this will be more useful for you in the future.